# Printing random characters instead of the same ones

Tags: python

sorry for the horrible title, I have no idea how I'd describe my problem.

I'm trying to generate a code that contains 15 characters. 7 of these are already given and will be called the "base". The other 8 have to be random from 0 to 9.

This is my code

```
numList = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"

whatSerial = input("Serial to generate?").upper()

def redmi4A(numList):
    return "8655920" + numList + numList + numList + numList + numList + numList + numList + numList + " -> Redmi 4A"
if whatSerial == "4A":
    for i in numList:
        print(redmi4A(i))
```

however the output looks like this:

```
865592011111111 -> Redmi 4A
865592022222222 -> Redmi 4A
865592033333333 -> Redmi 4A
865592044444444 -> Redmi 4A
865592055555555 -> Redmi 4A
865592066666666 -> Redmi 4A
865592077777777 -> Redmi 4A
865592088888888 -> Redmi 4A
865592099999999 -> Redmi 4A
865592000000000 -> Redmi 4A
```

as you can see it generates the base + 11111, 2222, 3333 etc.
I want the numbers after the base to output all possible solutions, so the numbers after the base would be in a random order.

Comment: N.b. `numList` defined in the first line is a tuple, not a list, and the `numList` argument to `redmi4A` is a string, also not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate random numbers, use the `random` module. Here's an example of how to generate a random number between `0` and `9`:

```
import random

random_num = random.randint(0, 9)
```

So your code would need to be changed to this:

```
import random

whatSerial = input("Serial to generate?").upper()

def redmi4A():
    return "8655920" + ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(8)]) + " -> Redmi 4A" # 8655920 + 8 random digits + " -> Redmi 4A"

if whatSerial == "4A":
    for i in range(10):
        print(redmi4A())
```

I hope this helps. If not, please try to clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: Just a little rectification, `range()` should have 8 instead of 7, as the upper bound is not included

Comment: @verbids when you change the `range()`, it simply changes the amount of times you will see a serial number being made. For example, if you use `range(1)` you will only see:
`865592019366958 -> Redmi 4A`
Whereas if you use `range(2)` you will see:
`865592019366958 -> Redmi 4A`
`865592015446593 -> Redmi 4A`

Comment: Thanks Vasu Deo.S, I've edited my answer.

Comment: `numList` is never used

Answer (score 3):

**TRY:-**

```
import random

numList = "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"

whatSerial = input("Serial to generate?").upper()

def redmi4A(opt):
    return "8655920" + "".join([random.choice(numList) for x in range(8)]) + " -> Redmi 4A"
if whatSerial == "4A":
    for i in numList:
        print(redmi4A(i))
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
865592087748606 -> Redmi 4A
865592065496599 -> Redmi 4A
865592061039159 -> Redmi 4A
865592004047509 -> Redmi 4A
865592089008612 -> Redmi 4A
865592065068787 -> Redmi 4A
865592015446593 -> Redmi 4A
865592095893322 -> Redmi 4A
865592074954808 -> Redmi 4A
865592019366958 -> Redmi 4A
```

There was one logical error in your code too, in function `redmi4A()` the argument name is the same as the name of the tuple `numList` which causes shadow name issues, and overrides the global tuple by the argument passed to the function(as both are under the same name). So, I changed the variable name to `opt` you can name it something else.